# "Text along path" decorations take absurdly long to be compiled for non-default font sizes

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-decorations, pgf-decorations

I'm trying to use a `text along path` `decoration` in `tikz-pgf` which causes absurd loading times, sometimes far longer than an hour if I want to print a whopping two (!!) words in for example `\large` font size. My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shapes.arrows,curvilinear,shadings,decorations.text}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{51,127,230}
\definecolor{olive2}{RGB}{64,196,0}
\definecolor{dorange}{RGB}{255,140,0}

\tikzfading[name=arrowfading, left color=transparent!0, right color=transparent!35]
\tikzset{
arrownode/.style={
    transform shape nonlinear=true,
    shape=double arrow, 
    line width=10mm,
    shape border rotate=180,
    upper left=cyan!25,
    lower left=dorange!5,
    upper right=olive!35,
    lower right=dorange!20,
    path fading=arrowfading
}
}
\makeatletter
\def\polartransformation{
\pgfmathsincos@{\pgf@x}
\pgf@x=\pgfmathresultx\pgf@y%
\pgf@y=\pgfmathresulty\pgf@y%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(-5,-5)}]
\pgftransformnonlinear{\polartransformation}
\node[arrownode,shading angle=0] (a) at (1.5*pi,-5) {\phantom{\hspace{2cm}Gleidende schaal\hspace{4cm}}};
\path[decorate,decoration={text along path, % this is the culprit
                text={\Huge{G L E I D E N D E S C H A A L}},
                text align=center,
                raise=-0.5ex
                }](a.west) -- (a.east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm considering externalization, but that would still require an actual print by the software, thus far yielding little result.

Comment: Instead of `text={\Huge{G L E I D E N D E S C H A A L}}`, use `text={|\Huge|G L E I D E N D E S C H A A L}`. See `text format delimiters` p. 603 of pgfmanual v3.0

Comment: @PaulGaborit, a quick answer for this one?

Comment: @PaulGessler Done...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `text={\Huge{G L E I D E N D E S C H A A L}}`, use `text={|\Huge|G L E I D E N D E S C H A A L}` (see section "text format delimiters" p.603 of pgfmanual v3.0).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shapes.arrows,curvilinear,shadings,decorations.text}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{51,127,230}
\definecolor{olive2}{RGB}{64,196,0}
\definecolor{dorange}{RGB}{255,140,0}

\tikzfading[name=arrowfading, left color=transparent!0, right color=transparent!35]
\tikzset{
arrownode/.style={
    transform shape nonlinear=true,
    shape=double arrow, 
    line width=10mm,
    shape border rotate=180,
    upper left=cyan!25,
    lower left=dorange!5,
    upper right=olive!35,
    lower right=dorange!20,
    path fading=arrowfading
}
}
\makeatletter
\def\polartransformation{
\pgfmathsincos@{\pgf@x}
\pgf@x=\pgfmathresultx\pgf@y%
\pgf@y=\pgfmathresulty\pgf@y%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}

\pgftransformnonlinear{\polartransformation}
\node[arrownode,shading angle=0] (a) at (1.5*pi,-5) {\phantom{\hspace{2cm}Gleidende schaal\hspace{4cm}}};
\path[decorate,decoration={text along path, % this is the culprit
                text={|\Huge|G L E I D E N D E S C H A A L},
                text align=center,
                raise=-0.5ex
                }](a.west) -- (a.east);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```