# Change size of text in tikz decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, tikz-decorations

I'm trying to draw some text along an arc, but I can't see how I can change the font size of the text I'm drawing.

```
\foreach \j/\k/\p in {1/30/December,31/61/November}{
    \draw [decoration={text along path, text={\p}, text align={center}, reverse path},decorate]
    (360/365*\j+90:5.2) arc (360/365*\j+90:360/365*\k+90:5.2);
}
```

I've tried `text={\tiny{\p}}` and `text={{\tiny \p}}` and `in {1/30/{\tiny December},...}`, but they didn't work.

I've tried putting `scale=0.5` in the draw command, but that just changes the radius of the arc not the size of the text.

The examples in the manual use `characters={scale=0.4}` in the decoration options but I get a compilation error when I try that (`I do not know the key to which you passed scale=0.5`).

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal example

Comment: `font=\tiny`   ..

Comment: Use `text={|\tiny|\p}`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171255/47927

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See section 50.7 “Text Decorations” of the [Ti*k*Z/PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), where it is explained that the default `text format delimiters` are pipes (`|`). There are also some examples in this section that nicely show how to style text along path.

In your case, you can use `text={|\tiny|\p}`, like in the following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \j/\k/\p in {1/30/December,31/61/November}{
    \draw [decoration={text along path, text={|\tiny|\p}, text align={center}, reverse path}, decorate]
    (360/365*\j+90:5.2) arc (360/365*\j+90:360/365*\k+90:5.2);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't see that bit in the manual. I still don't really understand why `characters={}` doesn't work.

Comment: It seems like `characters` can only be used with `text effects` and `text effects along path`. But I am not sure and didn't try this.